# How to create a decorator class that does not take any argument and can be imported by another class for API authentication

Tags: python-3.x, python-decorators

My user case is I want to create a decorator Util that I can consume throughout the application, I want it like a module and it should not take any arguments. There are many example of writing a function but very few for class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'''
from flask import make_response, jsonify
import functools

```
class IsAdmin(object):
  def __init__(self, arg):
      self._arg = arg #--> self._args will hold the method
      functools.update_wrapper(self, arg)
  def __call__(self, *param_arg): #param_arg will hold the method params(2,2)
      (status,msg) = util.isOwner()
      if status == True and msg == 'is Owner':
        #If there are decorator arguments, __call__() is only called onceas part of the decoration process. You can only give it a single argument,which is the function objectIf there are no decorator arguments, the functionto be decorated is passed to the constructor.>
        # if len(param_arg) == 1:
        #     def wrapper(*main_args): #--> here we are passing the values that we pass to the function
        #         retval = param_arg[0](self, main_args[0], main_args[1])
        #         return retval ** self._arg[0]
        #     return wrapper
        # else:
        # expo = 2
        retval = self._arg(self, *param_arg)
        return retval
    else:
        return "you are not the admin"
```

'''